# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

When I run the intellij idea maven install , it got the issue as this

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile

how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution , in the pom.xml file , your java version might not be correct ,  it is like your verion is older , update it to the current environment version , the issue is resolved

```
enter code here
<properties>
    <java.version>1.14</java.version>
</properties>
```